# Сервер не видит базу данных

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, connection, bottle

Я пишу рекомендательную систему по подбору жилья, создал 4 файла: (app.py - сервер),и client.py - запрос на сервер,model.py - алгоритм для извлечения ключевых слов,recommendstion.py - алгоритм рекомендации и какой бы запрос я бы не задал, сервер никогда ничего не приводит из бд, даже если я в тупую напишу текст из колонки, ничего не сработает...Я уже начал без использования алгоритма тупо включать сервер и писать запрос по типу "SELECT * FROM Apartments WHERE Area = 20" и никого результата нет, хотя такая колонка есть , в чем проблема?
код app.py

```
import sqlite3

from model import analyse_text
from bottle import run, route, Bottle, request, response
from recommendation import rec


app = Bottle('__main__')
connector = sqlite3.connect('identifier.db')

cursor = connector.cursor()


@app.route('/process', method=['POST', 'GET'])
def process_request():
    text = request.body.read().decode('utf-8')
    keywords = analyse_text(text)

    abs_query = f"SELECT * FROM Apartments WHERE Description LIKE '%cozy%'"
    # abs_query = rec(keywords)

    # Выполнение SQL-запроса
    cursor.execute(abs_query)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    best_result = sel_best(results)

    if best_result is not None:
        response.content_type = 'application/text'
        return f'Result: {best_result}'
    else:
        response.status = 404
        response.content_type = 'application/text'
        return 'No matching results found'


def sel_best(result):
    if result:
        result[0]
    else:
        return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(app=app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080', debug=True)
```

Comment: Как вы определили, что результата нет? Попробуйте ваши запросы, для начала, выполнить в самой БД и убедиться, что записи есть по вашим условиям. Попробуйте посмотреть, что лежит в `best_result`

Comment: Вот как раз проверил, такой запрос есть, но когда это делаешь на сервере - не робит

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в функции sel_best_result(),она всегда выводила None,я заменил ее на

```
c = []

    for i in results:
        c.append(i)

    response.content_type = 'application/text'
    return f"Result {c[0]}"
```